# не удаётся взять значения класса

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="article"> aaaa </div>

var ddd = document.getElementById('article');
alert(ddd.innerHTML);
```

Тут всё понятно, выводится содержимое элемента с id article, а как быть если нету id но есть класс? например как алертом вывести содержимое такого элемента:

```
<div class="article"> aaaa </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если не важна совместимость с IE то `document.getElementsByClassName` вернёт все элементы с требуемым классом. Иначе обход дерева DOM и проверка атрибута `class`. Вместо  `document` можно использовать родительский элемент, если он известен.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName не работает,нигде, написал свою функцию но это не то, на примере можите показать как с помощью getElementsByClassName сделать?

Comment: Вероятно вы где-то ошиблись, данная функция возвращает объект типа `HTMLCollection`, т. е. для получения содержимого тега вам необходимо написать следующее:
`document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[0].innerHTML` Впрочем @LightShock это уже написал

Comment: Думаю будет полезно http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = document.querySelector(".article").innerHTML;
alert(txt);
```

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) поддерживается всеми популярными браузерами и IE начиная с версии 8.
[Вот](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) таблица совместимости.
Если нужно вернуть HTMLCollection нужно использовать querySelectorAll. Преимущество в том, что можно вводить сложные CSS-селекторы, например:

```
document.querySelector("a[href*=google]");
document.querySelectorAll("div:contains('hello world')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
  <html>
      <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
      function show() {
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName('article')[0].innerHTML);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="article">####Содержимое класса####</div>
    <a href="#" onclick="show(); return false;">Показать содержимое класса</a>
  </body>
</html>
```